# Text_Changed problems

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

Hello i have a search box, that is a TextBox, that filters the ListBox.

I have an array of items and the code does next thing:

```
private async void SearchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Item a in arr)
    {
         if(a.Title.Contains(SearchTextBox.Text))
         {
             ListBox.Items.Add(a);
         }
    }
}
```

All works fine when i delete by 1 symbol, but when i hold backspace something strange happens, items start to duplicate or change their positions - **what is the problem and how to prevent this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see this is async, you need to synchronize this method

Create an instance object named _syncRoot:

```
private object _syncRoot = new Object();


private async void SearchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  lock( _syncRoot) 
  {
    ListBox.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Item a in arr)
    {
       if(a.Title.Contains(SearchTextBox.Text))
       {
           ListBox.Items.Add(a);
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And how should that help?

Comment: I've revised, I realize now this is an async method so your ListBox is getting modified by multiple threads of execution.  It needs to be synchronized.

Comment: Just because it is `async` does not mean there are multiple threads. The method is likely being re-entered on the same thread. In which case `lock` won't help.

Comment: but, won't this lock lead to that it will show previous result, not the current?

Comment: I don't think so, it's just forcing the calls to processed atomically.    Try it and see....

Comment: This doesn't do because i have await operators inside

Comment: Aha! Await operators! So it is a sync issue. It would have be more useful if you had posted the whole code since the beginning. And yes, Locks won't work with await keyword.

Comment: I have managed to get over it i just placed all items into a List, that i filtered NOT async this time and all worked fine. But you are correct that it was sync issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are likely re-entering the handler on the same thread (the UI thread) while you are looping. One option is to detach the handler upon entry and then reattach on exit. You will probably need to do a double check then that nothing else happened while you had it detached.

I am not as familiar with Window 8 apps, but filtering a `ListBox` based on a `TextBox` is very common. I would expect you to be able to use something like `CollectionViewSource.Filter` to do the filtering automatically (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466917/trigger-filter-on-collectionviewsource) for an example).

A basic implementation:

```
private void SearchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string initialText = SearchTextBox.Text;
    SearchTextBox.TextChanged -= SearchTextBox_TextChanged;
    do
    {
        ListBox.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Item a in arr)
        {
             if(a.Title.Contains(initialText))
             {
                ListBox.Items.Add(a);
             }
        }
    } while (SearchTextBox.Text != initialText)
    SearchTextBox.TextChanged += SearchTextBox_TextChanged;
}
```