# Update the List view observable collection using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, collections, observable

I have a `usercontrol`, with one list box and one list view control in it. For Listview i have bound the `observablecollection` of type `TrafficManager` class as shown below:

```
   private static ObservableCollection<TrafficManager> _trafficCollection;
            public ObservableCollection<TrafficManager> TrafficCollection
            {
                get { return _trafficCollection; }
                set
                {
                    _trafficCollection = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("TrafficCollection"); 
                }
            }
```

I have bound this to itemsource of list view. 
Now my requirement is on selection of the listbox item, i need to filter some items of the listview. For that i used a linq to get the desired rows from list view and added that to the list view collection. Before adding i did a listview Collection `TrafficCollection.Clear()` and then added to that collection.But now the issue is on selection of another item in list box i need the original listview contents again  to carry out the filtering using the linq again. Here once the `TrafficCollection.Clear()` executes the original observable collection data vanishes. How do i maintain a backup of original observable collection data `"TrafficCollection"` of listview. Remember i have only one view. Is there anyway to do this? Please let me know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497506/collectionviewsource-how-to-filter-data

Comment: You hold onto the original items instead of throwing them away.  Your VM can have more than one collection holding references to the same items.

Comment: Thank you, but can you let me know how to hold references to same class items. If I modify the items through add or remove won't the reference collection also get modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use CollectionViewSource filtering, refer [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-filtering/)

SO Link: [Trigger Filter on CollectionViewSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466917/trigger-filter-on-collectionviewsource)

this will not clear original collection.

Comment: Thanks. But i use a observable collection for list view and its in WPF.

Comment: yes it  is WPF and Instead of List, you can use ObservableCollection.

Comment: @santhosh see updated SO link. it covers MVVM implementation also

Comment: @WPFUser If you are interested in interactive help, feel free to visit the [WPF chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf). We cater to WPF w/ MVVM.