# WPF ListView to update automatically using INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, inotifypropertychanged

I have a ListView called ChosenListView in my UserControl. In my UserControl's constructor I set the DataContext to my ViewModel, which includes an ObservableCollection (called Elements) of elements that have a bool IsChosen property.

I want to have my ChosenListView display all elements in Elements whose IsChosen property is true. I want it to be automatically updated every time I change one of the elements IsChosen property.

I tried to utilize INotifyPropertyChanged, but I can't seem to get it to work and would appreciate any help.

I define here a CollectionViewSource:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <CollectionViewSource
                    x:Key="ChosenElementsViewSource"
                    x:Name="ChosenElementsViewSource"
                    Source="{Binding Elements}"
                    Filter="ChosenElementsViewSource_Filter"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

This is the filter:

```
private void ChosenElementsViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    e.Accepted = e.Item is ChoosableElement choosableElement &&
        choosableElement.IsChosen;
}
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
private class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ChoosableElement> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

In my UserControl's constructor I set DataContext to a new instance of my ViewModel, and initialize Elements based on my database, where all elements start with IsChosen=false.

My ListView defines an ItemsSource in the XAML:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ChosenElementsViewSource}}"
```

Lastly, my ChoosableElement is defined as follows:

```
private class ChoosableElement : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Element Element { get; set; }

    private bool isChosen = false;
    public bool IsChosen
    {
        get { return isChosen; }
        set
        {
            if (isChosen != value)
            {
                isChosen = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsChosen));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: you can configure IsLiveFilteringRequested = true for CollectionViewSource and add required LiveFilteringProperties

Comment: Thanks! Can you please elaborate? What do these things do? (Also, what do you mean by "add required LiveFilteringProperties"?

Comment: @Idra LiveFiltering example here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466917/trigger-filter-on-collectionviewsource#30738465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refresh the `CollectionViewSource` to invoke the `Filter` event handler each time the `IsChosen` property is set.

You can either do this programmatically yourself by handling the `PropertyChanged` event for all items in the code-behind of the `UserControl`. Something like this:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var viewModel = new ViewModel();
        DataContext = viewModel;

        if (viewModel.Elements != null)
        {
            viewModel.Elements.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
            foreach (object item in viewModel.Elements)
                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged
                    += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnPropertyChanged);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
            foreach (object item in e.NewItems)
                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged
                        += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnPropertyChanged);

        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (object item in e.OldItems)
                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged
                        -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnPropertyChanged);
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ChoosableElement.IsChosen))
        {
            (Resources["ChosenElementsViewSource"] as CollectionViewSource)?
                .View.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void ChosenElementsViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Accepted = e.Item is ChoosableElement choosableElement &&
            choosableElement.IsChosen;
    }

    ...
}
```

Or you could enabling the live filtering feature that was introduced in the .NET Framework 4.5 directly on the `CollectionViewSource` in the XAML markup:

```
<CollectionViewSource
    x:Key="ChosenElementsViewSource"
    x:Name="ChosenElementsViewSource"
    Source="{Binding Elements}"
    Filter="ChosenElementsViewSource_Filter"
    IsLiveFilteringRequested="True"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
        <system:String>IsChosen</system:String>
    </CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Comment: Holy @$#$ this works perfectly! <3 I will never understand WPF. XD Thank you.